# Does a form timer maintain state during sleep/hibernate?

Tags: vb.net

If I have an event that starts a timer with an interval of say, 30 minutes, and 15 minutes later, the computer the app is running on sleeps (Suspend to RAM) or Hibernates (Suspend to Disk), and is brought back online after ten minutes, will the timer raise its Tick event in 5 minutes (30 minutes REAL time from the start) or 15 minutes (30 minutes RUNTIME from the start)?

Comment: What issues did you run into when you tried it?

Comment: The context is an alarm clock Application written for my VB course midterm project.  It wasn't raising alarms at the right time in longer testing - now I know why.  Going to have to code around that somehow.  An alarm that sets itself back however long your system's been asleep isn't very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer maintains whatever state it was in before hibernation or suspension.  When the system resumes from hibernate/restore, it will resume from where it was before.  In other words, the timer will not run while the system is asleep.